# HTML hyperlink to a specific page of a pdf file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Consider a very simple link to a pdf file in HTML:

```
<a target="_blank" href="mypdf.pdf">Link to pdf</a>
```

Of course, when the user clicks on the link, the pdf is open and the first page is shown in the browser.

Is there a way create a link to a specific page of the pdf? I was wondering if there is some command like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="mypdf.pdf#11">Link to page 11 of the pdf</a>
```

or some trick based on Javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found answer on adobe forum https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2345594.

After # you should write something like #page=3 for example, to move automatically to page 3.

Answer (score 3):

The following should do the trick

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.exampleurl.com/file.pdf#page=4">
```

You can also do chapters if needed but this needs a correctly formatted PDF.

Thanks